# How can I override set method in class to work with array.push?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to override `set` method for some property in my object.

```
class MyClass extends Element {
  set locations(markers) {
    //setter implementation
  }
}
```

Works **correctly** when setting the whole array:
`obj.locations = ['location1', 'location2'];`

I want to expose an API that `locations` can be set intuitively, with:
`obj.locations.push('location3');`
But it doesn't even pass through the setter implementation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `push` line does not call the setter. You're not assigning an array, but trying to mutate it. For that to work you need to define the *getter*.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
class MyClass {
  set locations(markers) {
    this._locations = markers;
  }
  get locations() {
    return this._locations; // Make sure to return an array instance
  }
}

var elem = new MyClass;

elem.locations = [];
elem.locations.push("test");
console.log(elem.locations);
```

If you cannot return an array that would be directly linked to the state of the instance, then let the getter return an object that implements itself `push` and any other methods you'd like it to expose.

Comment: This is way better solution than mine :) +1

Comment: @Terry You should not have delete your answer. :)

Comment: I really honestly think yours is better: and I totally forgot about `getter` in classes ;) silly me!